# Which of following is false?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Which of following is\are false ?

A. $\pi$ is algebraic over field of Real numbers.

B. $\pi$ is transcendental over field of Real numbers.

C. $x^2 - 2$ is irreducible over field of Real numbers.

D. The Galois group of finite extension of finite fields is abelian.

I think A is false. I am not sure though

Comment: A is false, B is true. C is false as well. ($x^2-2=(x+\sqrt2)(x-\sqrt2)$.) I didn't learn about finite fields in my abstract algebra class, so someone else will have to handle the last one.

Comment: @CarlHeckman:  I think that A is true, since $\pi$ is a root of the equation $x-\pi=0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, you're right. $\pi$ is transcendental over the field of *rational* numbers. (Stupid trick question ...)

Comment: @CarlHeckman: One of the problems with multiple choice tests (I have never given one) is the temptation they pose to try to trick people.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Which is false then ?

Comment: D is true - the Galois group of any finite extension of a finite field is cyclic.

Comment: Now you've got the complete answer; only B and C are false.

Comment: @CarlHeckman : You're not alert today! $\qquad$

Comment: I didn't expect a trick question here ... or the Spanish Inquisition, for that matter!

Comment: @CarlHeckman : I don't think it's a trick question; the point is just that the words "over the field of real numbers" mean something. $\qquad$

Answer (score 5):

A is true, since $\pi$ is the root of a polynomial with coefficient in the real numbers, namely
$$1x + (-\pi)=0.$$

(Usually when one says a number is "algebraic" one means over the field of rational numbers, not the field of real numbers.  By that definition, $\pi$ is not algebraic.)

Comment: Yeah, André said this above.

Comment: @CarlHeckman It's important that questions get answered, so they don't stay in the ''unanswered'' queue. I hope you did not downvote this answer for that reason (if you were the downvoter).

Comment: Well, you didn't answer it completely. I provided an answer to another part below.

Comment: @AlexWertheim There's a bug in the stackexchange website then; when I click on unanswered questions, there are often questions which have been answered on the results.

Comment: @user26857 : The point is that there is a first-degree coefficient, which is $1$, and a constant coefficient, which is $-\pi$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

C is false as well. $x^2-2=(x+\sqrt2)(x-\sqrt2)$.